# Question of accessing data in Cache object that is updating

Tags: asp.net

What happen if multiple clients try to access objects in cache that are undergoing update?

Can anybody give any information?

Thanks,

Ricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Web.Caching.Cache internally uses Monitor class for synchronization. So if there is undergoing updates, your **reader** threads will be blocked.